# Converting a program from FreeBASIC to Python: globalizing variables

Tags: python, oop, global-variables, freebasic

In a previous post, I was told I am coding in Python like you would in BASIC (I am not "thinking" in Python yet). This is probably true and this is why I need help. This being said, I have read one book about Python so far (*Bytes of Python*), I bought two more books online (one of which is *Invent with Python*, which I am reading) and I did many tutorials from The New Boston. Still, my question might sound newbie-ish to you.

In FreeBasic, variables are all globalized. In Python, I have to globalize them for every single new function I create. This isn't very practical. So what am I expected to do? How would a "native Python speaker" tackle this problem? Below you'll find a small program I have created where I globalize in all my variables inside functions.

```
#-*- coding: iso8859_1 -*-

import random

ca1 = 10
ca2 = 10
taco = 20
pv1 = random.randint(1,10)
pv2 = random.randint(1,10)
cnt = 0
pv1Dep = pv1
pv2Dep = pv2
ast = "*" * 7
d20_1 = random.randint(1,20)
d8_1 = random.randint(1,8)
d20_2 = random.randint(1,20)
d8_2 = random.randint(1,8)

def intro():
    global ca1
    global ca2
    global taco
    global pv1
    global pv2
    global cnt
    global pv1Dep
    global pv2Dep
    global d20_1
    global d8_1
    global d20_2
    global d8_2


    print "Imaginez deux guerriers de D&D 2e édition qui se battent."
    print
    print "Guerrier 1: " + str(pv1) + " PV, épée longue (1-8 points de dégât), TACO de 20, CA de " + str(ca1) + "."
    print "Guerrier 2: " + str(pv2) + " PV, épée longue (1-8 points de dégât), TACO de 20, CA de " + str(ca2) + "."
    print

def nouveauCombat():
    global ca1
    global ca2
    global taco
    global pv1
    global pv2
    global cnt
    global pv1Dep
    global pv2Dep
    global d20_1
    global d8_1
    global d20_2
    global d8_2

    print ast + "NOUVEAU COMBAT" + ast
    print
    while ((pv1 > 0) and (pv2 > 0)):
        cnt = cnt + 1
        print ast + "ROUND " + str(cnt) + ": INITIATIVE" + ast
        print
        calcInitiative()
        print
    print ast + "RESULTAT" + ast
    print
    resultat()

def calcInitiative():
    global ca1
    global ca2
    global taco
    global pv1
    global pv2
    global cnt
    global pv1Dep
    global pv2Dep
    global d20_1
    global d8_1
    global d20_2
    global d8_2

    initiative1 = random.randint(1,10)
    initiative2 = random.randint(1,10)
    print "Le guerrier 1 fait son jet d'initiative."
    print str(initiative1) + "!"
    print
    print "Le guerrier 2 fait son jet d'initiative."
    print str(initiative2) + "!"
    print
    if initiative1 == initiative2:
        print "Les deux guerriers attaquent au même moment."
        print
        print ast + "ROUND " + str(cnt) + ": ATTAQUE" + ast
        print
        attaque1()
        print
        attaque2()
    elif initiative1 < initiative2:
        print "Le guerrier 1 attaque en premier."
        print
        print ast + "ROUND " + str(cnt) + ": ATTAQUE" + ast
        print
        attaque1()
        print
        if pv2 > 0:
            print
            attaque2()
    else:
        print "Le guerrier 2 attaque en premier."
        print
        print ast + "ROUND " + str(cnt) + ": ATTAQUE" + ast
        print
        attaque2()
        print
        if pv1 > 0:
            print
            attaque2()

def attaque1():
    global ca1
    global ca2
    global taco
    global pv1
    global pv2
    global cnt
    global pv1Dep
    global pv2Dep
    global d20_1
    global d8_1
    global d20_2
    global d8_2

    print "Le guerrier 1 fait son jet de toucher."
    print str(d20_1) + "!"
    if d20_1 >= ca2:
        print "Touché!"
        pv2 = pv2 - d8_1
        print str(d8_1) + " points de dégât!"
        print "Le guerrier 2 est à " + str(pv2) + "/" + str(pv2Dep) + " PV!"
    else:
        print "Raté!"

def attaque2():
    global ca1
    global ca2
    global taco
    global pv1
    global pv2
    global cnt
    global pv1Dep
    global pv2Dep
    global d20_1
    global d8_1
    global d20_2
    global d8_2

    print "Le guerrier 2 fait son jet de toucher."
    print str(d20_2) + "!"
    if d20_2 >= ca1:
        print "Touché!"
        pv1 = pv1 - d8_2
        print str(d8_2) + " points de dégât!"
        print "Le guerrier 1 est à " + str(pv1) + "/" + str(pv1Dep) + " PV!"
    else:
        print "Raté!"

def resultat():
    global ca1
    global ca2
    global taco
    global pv1
    global pv2
    global cnt
    global pv1Dep
    global pv2Dep
    global d20_1
    global d8_1
    global d20_2
    global d8_2

    print "Le combat prend fin au round " + str(cnt) + "."
    print

    if pv1 == pv1Dep:
        print "Le guerrier 1 n'a pas la moindre égratignure."
    elif pv1 > 0:
        print "Le guerrier 1 est blessé."
    else:
        print "Le guerrier 1 est mort."

    print "Il finit le combat avec " + str(pv1) + "/" +str (pv1Dep) + " PV."
    print

    if pv2 == pv2Dep:
        print "Le guerrier 2 n'a pas la moindre égratignure."
    elif pv2 > 0:
        print "Le guerrier 2 est blessé."
    else:
        print "Le guerrier 2 est mort."

    print "Il finit le combat avec " + str(pv2) + "/" +str (pv2Dep) + " PV."
    print

intro()
nouveauCombat()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've reorganized your program to show you the basics of [object oriented programming](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Object-oriented_programming). You need to learn about classes and objects. You should also look at [string formatting](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#formatstrings) for the right way to put strings together.

Basically, you create two player objects, and then create a combat object for those two players. Then, you call *methods* on the combat *object* in order to actually do the combat. `self` is how an *instance* of a *class* refers to itself. Any good Python tutorial should teach you about all of these things.

The only remaining global variable is a constant, `ast`. Global constants can occasionally be OK.

```
#-*- coding: iso8859_1 -*-
import random
ast = "*" * 7

class Player(object):
    def __init__(self, num, ca):
        self.ca = ca
        self.num = num
        self.pv = random.randint(1,10)
        self.d20 = random.randint(1,20)
        self.d8 = random.randint(1,8)
        self.pvDep= self.pv

class Combat(object):
    def __init__(self, player1, player2):
        self.player1 = player1
        self.player2 = player2
        self.cnt = 0

    def intro(self):
        print "Imaginez deux guerriers de D&D 2e édition qui se battent."
        print
        print "Guerrier 1: " + str(player1.pv) + " PV, épée longue (1-8 points de dégât), TACO de 20, CA de " + str(player1.ca) + "."
        print "Guerrier 2: " + str(player2.pv) + " PV, épée longue (1-8 points de dégât), TACO de 20, CA de " + str(player2.ca) + "."
        print

    def nouveauCombat(self):
        print ast + "NOUVEAU COMBAT" + ast
        print
        while ((self.player1.pv > 0) and (self.player2.pv > 0)):
            self.cnt = self.cnt + 1
            print ast + "ROUND " + str(self.cnt) + ": INITIATIVE" + ast
            print
            self.calcInitiative()
            print
        print ast + "RESULTAT" + ast
        print
        self.resultat()

    def calcInitiative(self):
        initiative1 = random.randint(1,10)
        initiative2 = random.randint(1,10)
        print "Le guerrier 1 fait son jet d'initiative."
        print str(initiative1) + "!"
        print
        print "Le guerrier 2 fait son jet d'initiative."
        print str(initiative2) + "!"
        print
        if initiative1 == initiative2:
            print "Les deux guerriers attaquent au même moment."
            print
            print ast + "ROUND " + str(self.cnt) + ": ATTAQUE" + ast
            print
            self.attaque(self.player1, self.player2)
            print
            self.attaque(self.player2, self.player1)
        elif initiative1 < initiative2:
            print "Le guerrier 1 attaque en premier."
            print
            print ast + "ROUND " + str(self.cnt) + ": ATTAQUE" + ast
            print
            self.attaque(self.player1, self.player2)
            print
            if self.player2.pv > 0:
                print
                self.attaque(self.player2, self.player1)
        else:
            print "Le guerrier 2 attaque en premier."
            print
            print ast + "ROUND " + str(self.cnt) + ": ATTAQUE" + ast
            print
            self.attaque(self.player2, self.player1)
            print
            if self.player1.pv > 0:
                print
                self.attaque(self.player1, self.player2)

    def attaque(self, player1, player2):
        print "Le guerrier" + str(player1.num) + " fait son jet de toucher."
        print str(player1.d20) + "!"
        if player1.d20 >= player2.ca:
            print "Touché!"
            player2.pv = player2.pv - player1.d8
            print str(player1.d8) + " points de dégât!"
            print "Le guerrier 2 est à " + str(player2.pv) + "/" + str(player2.pvDep) + " PV!"
        else:
            print "Raté!"

    def resultat(self):
        print "Le combat prend fin au round " + str(self.cnt) + "."
        print

        if player1.pv == player1.pvDep:
            print "Le guerrier 1 n'a pas la moindre égratignure."
        elif player1.pv > 0:
            print "Le guerrier 1 est blessé."
        else:
            print "Le guerrier 1 est mort."

        print "Il finit le combat avec " + str(player1.pv) + "/" +str (player1.pvDep) + " PV."
        print

        if player2.pv == player2.pvDep:
            print "Le guerrier 2 n'a pas la moindre égratignure."
        elif player2.pv > 0:
            print "Le guerrier 2 est blessé."
        else:
            print "Le guerrier 2 est mort."

        print "Il finit le combat avec " + str(player2.pv) + "/" +str (player2.pvDep) + " PV."
        print


player1 = Player(1, 10)
player2 = Player(2, 10)
combat = Combat(player1, player2)
combat.intro()
combat.nouveauCombat()
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to declare a name as global unless you are going to assign to it.

```
a = 1
b = 2
def foo():
    global b
    print a # prints 1
    b = 3
foo()
print b # prints 3
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer his question -- what should he do instead of use global variables?

Answer (score 2):

In python, as in many modern languages, prolific use of global variables is considered an anti-pattern.  There are lots of reasons why:

- it obstructs function reentrancy, which is important for efficient multi-threaded code.
- it makes unit testing harder, which is helpful on medium to large projects
- it makes modules more interdependent, which makes it harder to track down problems and to fix them once they are found.

You should endevor to *pass* the data each function needs:

```
def foo():
    bar = 10
    baz(bar)

def baz(bar):
    print bar
```

If you need to capture state from one function to the next, you can wrap that into a class.

```
class quux(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1
        self.b = "two"

def foo():
    bar = quux()
    baz(bar)
    print bar.a, bar.b

def baz(bar):
    bar.a = len(bar.b)
```

In summary, You almost never *need* globals, but in many cases, you need to have something that is *not* global.

Answer (score 1):

Global variables by default are widely (universally?) considered a design flaw. If you want to write "Pythonic" code, you should strive to have the smallest possible amount of global state.

Comment: Yes, but how does he do that? He hasn't done this sort of programming before

Comment: You should pass any data that a function actually needs as arguments. Looking at the example, it would probably be cleanest to create a class, but assuming you don't want to throw too many new ideas into the mix at once, explicit parameters are a perfectly acceptable option.